# I am using MATLAB HDL coder to convert matlab coder and currently having some error

Tags: matlab, hdl-coder

I am not able to get this error removed. Can someone please help me. The problem is it is showing some error in step 4 while generation of hdl code.

```
 function [Rxx]=autom(X)    % [Rxx]=autom(x)
Rxx=zeros(1,1024);
for m=1: 1025
for n=1: 1025-m
Rxx(m)=Rxx(m)+X(n)*X(n+m-1);

end
end
```

%testbench

```
N=1024;                            % Number of samples
f1=1;                              % Frequency of the sinewave
FS=200;                            % Sampling Frequency
n=0:1023;                           % Sample index numbers
X=zeros(1,1024);
% X=sin(2*pi*1*(0:1023)/200);
X=sin((2*pi*1.*n)./200);
t=[1:1024]*(1/200);
%ti=f1*n/FS;
%x=sin(2*pi*ti);                    % Generate the signal, x(n) 
%t1=[1:N]; 
%t=t1*(1/FS);                          % Prepare a time axis

subplot(2,1,1);                    % Prepare the figure
plot(t,X);        
title('Sinwave of frequency 1000Hz [FS=8000Hz]');
xlabel('Time, [s]');
ylabel('Amplitude');
grid;

Rxx = autom(X(1:1024));                                % Calculate its autocorrelation
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(Rxx);
title('Autocorrelation function of the sinewave'); % Plot the autocorrelation 
xlabel('lags');
ylabel('Autocorrelation');
```

[image: Errors i am getting]

Answer (score 0):

The error says: "[...] unsuported dynamic matrix `X`[...]"

Your problem is that in your function you are doing `X(n)*X(n+m-1);` and it seem to be understanding that this is dynamically changing the size of the matrix. I suspect in fact that the error is in `Rxx`

Note that your `X` is 1024 on length, but your iterations of `n` and `m` are 1025 in length. `Rxx` is 1024 on length, but you do `Rxx(m)` and `m` goes up to 1025, thus dynamically changing its size (MATLAB will increase the size of `Rxx` from 1024 to 1025, *dynamically*)

Are you sure you dont want

```
function [Rxx]=autom(X)    % [Rxx]=autom(x)
Rxx=zeros(1,1024);
for m=1: 1024
  for n=1: 1024-m
    Rxx(m)=Rxx(m)+X(n)*X(n+m-1);
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry but i tried that it didnt work. Can you suggest me some way so that i can get rid of dynamic matrix and get it done somehow as scalar?

Comment: @maudoodahmed you dont seem to understand what a dynamic matrix is or what a scalar is. A dynamic matrix is a matrix that changes size. The code I provided makes matrices that are not dynamic. But I dont know much about HDL generation code, so I can not help you more than this, apologies

Comment: Ok. Thanks alot.